# .htaccess RewriteRule issue on Windows Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

On a windows server we run Helicon Ape for running `.htaccess` rules and installed PHP. I've below lines in a `.htaccess` file in root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ test/handle.php?path=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I wrote the below code in `handle.php` file.

```
echo $_GET["path"];
exit;
```

When I enter any url like this : `http://mysite.com/test/test.zip` or `http://mysite/test/FILENAME.EXT` instead printing `FILENAME.EXT` it just prints `handle.php` as output!! what's wrong?

Comment: Most likely PHP isn't setup properly for your webserver. Create a test.php and put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in to see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a condition to prevent rewriting handle.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/test/handle.php$
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ test/handle.php?path=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the output is `handle.php` yet! i'm really confused!

Comment: @Bob, I think the leading slash in your RewriteCond pattern should be removed.

Comment: I found that u updated the code, new rules work like a charm!